# Can I install plywood over a concrete slab to raise the subfloor height?

Tags: flooring, subfloor

We bought a house recently. The living room has a slab concrete and tile above it. The kitchen, dining and hallways are above the basement with plywood then hardwood (ugly) then vinyl at the top.

We want to replace the vinyl flooring with vinyl plank flooring all around. Can we remove the tile, put a vapor barrier, then put plywood to make it the same height as the hardwood so the new vinyl planks can go over it evenly?

Comment: Hardwood is rarely ugly. The current finish or condition may be, but underneath is gold. I can't imagine putting plastic over that. My $.015.

Comment: The color and the size of the hardwood planks are a no no. However I want to keep it just in case. That's why we want to put new floor over it instead of removing the hardwood.

Comment: Why would yiu remove the tile from the concrete?

Comment: The tile is uneven and in some spots the deviation is a lot. Also I thought it would be easier to match the hardwoods's height with plywood than the tile.